# Mixing property of a iid process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, mixing

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathcal{N_0}}$ an i.i.d. sequence on a generic $E$, $\tau$ be the measure preserving shift operator and suppose there exist, for $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$,the product sigma algebra, $A^\epsilon$ and $B^\epsilon$ such that $P[A\triangle 
 A^{\epsilon}]<\epsilon$ and $P[B\triangle 
 B^{\epsilon}]<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Suppose also that for big $n$, $A^{\epsilon}$ and $\tau^{-n}(B^\epsilon)$ are independent.

In Example 20.26 of Probability Theory by A. Klenke (3rd version), it is shown that

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|P[A\cap \tau^{-n}(B)]-P[A]P[\tau^{-n}(B)]|\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty}|P[A^\epsilon\cap \tau^{-n}(B^\epsilon)]-P[A^\epsilon]P[\tau^{-n}(B^\epsilon)]|+4\epsilon
$$

and so the author concludes that the process is mixing.

**How can I get to this bound?** I do not understand how to obtain the $4\epsilon$ term.

Please, let me know if more context is needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \mathbf{1}_{E\cap F}-\mathbf{1}_{E'\cap F'}\right\rvert
&=\left\lvert \mathbf{1}_{E}\mathbf{1}_{F}-\mathbf{1}_{E'}\mathbf{1}_{F'}\right\rvert\\
&=\left\lvert \mathbf{1}_{E}\left(\mathbf{1}_{F}-\mathbf{1}_{F'}\right)+\left(\mathbf{1}_{E}-\mathbf{1}_{E'}\right)\mathbf{1}_{F'}\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \mathbf{1}_{F\Delta F'}+\mathbf{1}_{E\Delta E'},
\end{align}
we derive that
$$
\left\vert\mathbb P(E\cap F)-\mathbb P(E'\cap F')\right\rvert
\leqslant \mathbb P(E\Delta E')+\mathbb P(F\Delta F').
$$
I guess that $\tau$ is measure preserving hence applying the previous inequality to $E=A$, $F=\tau^{-n}B$, $E'=A^\varepsilon$ and $F'=\tau^{-n}B^\varepsilon$, we get that
$$
\mathbb P(A\cap \tau^{-n}B)\leqslant 2\varepsilon+\mathbb P(A^\varepsilon\cap \tau^{-n}B^\varepsilon).
$$

Comment: I edited to correct a small error in the last sentence but it got rejected. It should be $E=A, F=\tau^{-n}B, E'=A^\varepsilon, F'=\tau^{-n}B^\varepsilon$. I do not know why they rejected it. Correct if I am wrong. Thanks @Davide Giraudo

Comment: @Enrico Yes you are right. I have corrected, thanks for having spotted this.